# Finding missing sequence numbers

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, sequence

I want to create a table to find missing sequence numbers. Sequence number between 0 to 70000 after reaching 70000 it becomes 0. In a particular period of time I need to find those missing records.

Answer (score 6):

This solution is based on statement which generates all natural numbers from 1 to some limit you set:

```
SELECT ROWNUM N FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 7000
```

Second part of this solution is Oracle `MINUS` operator (more commonly known as `EXCEPT`), which is designed to subtract sets.

In other words, final query is:

```
SELECT ROWNUM id FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 7000
MINUS
SELECT id FROM mytable
```

[**SQLFiddle demo for 20 numbers**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/23b3a/2).

Answer (score 3):

You may use [Lead and lag functions](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/lag-lead-analytic-functions.php) to detect the gaps in the sequence.
The solution will not limit you for a specific upper bound number like 70000.
**Detecting**:

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT lag(c.id) over(ORDER BY id) last_id,
               c.id curr_id,
               lead(c.id) over(ORDER BY id) next_id
          FROM mytable c
         order by id)
 WHERE nvl(last_id, curr_id) + 1 <> curr_id
   AND last_id IS NOT NULL
```

[***Sqlfiddle demo***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/23b3a/19). 
**Traversing**:

```
begin
  FOR x IN (SELECT *
              FROM (SELECT lag(c.id) over(ORDER BY id) last_id,
                           c.id curr_id,
                           lead(c.id) over(ORDER BY id) next_id
                      FROM mytable c order by id)
             WHERE nvl(last_id, curr_id) + 1 <> curr_id AND 
             last_id IS NOT NULL
            ) LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line('last_id :' || x.last_id);
    dbms_output.put_line('curr_id :' || x.curr_id);
    dbms_output.put_line('next_id :' || x.next_id);
    dbms_output.put('gaps found: ');
    for j in x.last_id + 1 .. nvl(x.next_id,x.curr_id) - 1   loop
      if  j != x.curr_id then
      dbms_output.put(j || ', ');
      end if;      
    end loop;
    dbms_output.put_line('');
    dbms_output.put_line('*****');
  end loop;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

I stole this from Tom Kyte a while ago:

```
select  id, one_before, Diff, dense_rank() over (order by Diff desc) rank from (
select  id, one_before,
            case when (id - one_before) > 1 then (id - one_before)
           else 1
           end Diff
 from (
       select id, lag(id) over(order by id) one_before
      from table_name order by id) )
```

The original discussion is located at http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:8146178058075.